My compiled .exe file disappears after running it – could Windows Defender be the issue?
I am encountering a strange issue when compiling and running a program in Visual Studio Code on Windows. Here's what happens:

I wrote a program to add files to a database. Initially, I tested it
with external files, and it worked fine.
After integrating the file manipulation code into my source code, I
encountered some errors. I fixed those and tried to run the program.
Upon running the .exe file, it disappeared from the directory
without any error messages.

I suspected Windows Defender might be causing this, as I found a 13-year-old article suggesting it could delete files it deems unsafe.
I added exclusions in Windows Defender for both the .exe file and the project folder. However, the issue persists.
I tested the setup by compiling a simple "Hello, World" program, and it worked fine. This issue only occurs with the program involving file operations.
What I've Tried:
Running Visual Studio Code as an administrator.
Adding exclusions in Windows Defender for the .exe file and the entire project folder.
What might be causing it:
 case 5:
        std::cout << "Enter the file path to upload: ";
        std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, filePath);

        // Insert the file into the database and display its content.
        if (insertFileIntoDatabase(db, filePath)) {
            printDatabaseContent(db);
        }
        std::cout << "uploading file(s)..." << std::endl;
        break;
    case 9:
        std::cout << "Exiting the program...\n";
        return;
    default:
        std::cerr << "Invalid choice. Please try again.\n";
}
}

I suspect that this is the problem, however I just don't understand why, and I can't find a way to fix my problem.
This is the code where the user inputs a file path, and the program attempts to insert the file into the database. Could this operation be causing Windows Defender to flag and remove the .exe file?

¿Which line is executed when file is removed? ¿Have you checked Windows Defender's journal to find out whether it actually removed the file? ¿Is your project folder kept in location backed by OneDrive or some other cloud storage provider?

@user7860670, yes I checked the log and the journal it says only that there might be suspect files and the pc might be vulnerable, when I click on the warning it just sends me to settings to turn on, it says "The settings that can block applications possibly dangereus is desactivated. You're pc can be vulenrable", and I don't understand why are people downvoting my question? and I don't know wich line is causing the problem, because I can't even compile the code

Have you checked the build log and verified that the code is building? Can you look at the build command that was executed in the terminal and run it from a command prompt or powershell or perhaps the msys2 terminal and see if you get an executable in that case. Can you attempt to completely disable windows defender and see if that works?

@drescherjm Thank you alot, It's an habit that I should start to take, read these logs apparently my library (sqlite3) wasn't linked properly in the tasks manager, what I don't understand is how it happened, if before I could run my code without problems
